# Numerical variable from mySQL is truncated in php mail using utf-8

Tags: php, email

I try to include a numerical variable from a database into a mail, using utf-8 encoding.

Here is the php code:

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT prix FROM offres WHERE rang=?');
$req->execute(array(1));
$donnees=$req->fetch();

$passage_ligne = "\n";

$v = 10.15;
$text='essai1 = '.$v;
$text.=$passage_ligne;
$text.= 'essai2 = '.$donnees['prix'];
$text.=' here is a french accent: é';
$v=$donnees['prix'];
$text.=$passage_ligne."essai3 = ".$v;

echo $text;

$from='xxx@wanadoo.fr';
$replyto='xxx@wanadoo.fr';
$Xmailer='PHP/';

$header = 'From: '. $from . $passage_ligne .'Reply-To: '. $replyto . $passage_ligne .'X-Mailer: '. $Xmailer . phpversion();
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0". $passage_ligne;
$header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8". $passage_ligne;
$header.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable". $passage_ligne;
$passage_ligne .'X-Mailer: '. $Xmailer . phpversion();

mail('xxxr@wanadoo.fr','sujet',$text,$header);
```

The numerical variable $donnees['prix'] = 18 does show up on the screen:

```
essai1 = 10.15 essai2 = 18 here is a french accent: Ã© essai3 = 18
```

But not in the mail, where it is truncated to "8":

```
essai1 = 10.15
essai2 =8 here is a french accent: é
essai3 =8
```

If I use the following header:

```
$header = 'From: '. $from . $passage_ligne .'Reply-To: '. $replyto . $passage_ligne .'X-Mailer: '. $Xmailer . phpversion();
```

The numerical variable shows up corectly in the mail, but not the accents:

```
essai1 = 10.15
essai2 = 18 here is a french accent: Ã©
essai3 = 18
```

Any way to get both in the same mail ? - Thanks

Comment: Related? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I tried to set the database to utf8-mb4 with no change.
I have just noticed: the popup of Mozilla Thunderbird annoucing the mail correctly displays the text. It is only in the mail body that the text is truncated (the mail source is also correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` character has special meaning in [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding. It's used as the prefix for escape sequences; it's followed by 2 hex digits to encode non-printing characters.

In your case, you're sending `= 18`. The two characters after `=` are taken to be the hex code `1`.

If you want to send a literal `=` in quoted-printable mail, you need to encode it as `=3D`.

```
$v = 10.15;
$text='essai1 =3D '.$v;
$text.=$passage_ligne;
$text.= 'essai2 =3D '.$donnees['prix'];
$text.=' here is a french accent: é';
$v=$donnees['prix'];
$text.=$passage_ligne."essai3 =3D ".$v;
```

Or you could use the `quoted_printable_encode` function.

```
mail('xxxr@wanadoo.fr','sujet',quoted_printable_encode($text),$header);
```

The latter is probably the best solution, it might also solve your problem with the accented characters.